How are Boggarts created?
We know a boggart can be destroyed by Riddikulus.
We also know that Boggarts can move as well.

"Boggarts like dark,
enclosed spaces," said Professor Lupin. "Wardrobes, the gap beneath
beds, the cupboards under sinks -- I've even met one that had lodged
itself in a grandfather clock. This one moved in yesterday
afternoon, and I asked the headmaster if the staff would leave it to
give my third years some practice."

Do we have any info, canon or interviews, on how are boggarts created?

I assumed boggarts were just magical creatures that reproduce reproductively, but they're not listed in Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them, so I guess they're something else?

That charm doesn't kill them (you cannot kill that which does not live), but it does repel and depower them; "The charm that repels a Boggart is simple, yet it requires force of mind. You see, the thing that really finishes a Boggart is laughter. What you need to do is force it to assume a shape that you find amusing"

So, you see, when a mommy boggart and a daddy boggart love each other very much, they have a very special hug...

Per JKR's own writings, they appear to have arisen spontaneously, like a lot of other 'amortal' creatures and beings.

Like a poltergeist, a Boggart is not and never has been truly alive.
It is one of the strange non-beings that populates the magical world,
for which there is no equivalent in the Muggle realm. Boggarts can be
made to disappear, but more Boggarts will inevitably arise to take
their place. Like poltergeists and the more sinister Dementors, they
seem to be generated and sustained by human emotions.
Boggart By J.K. Rowling

